# getting error in mapping array elements into list items

Tags: reactjs

I have a written a simple ReactJS code to get an array of records from Store class using getRecords method and I am printing that array in View component inside a list component using map function. But I am getting an error that is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. Please tell what is the issue in my code?

**main.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import View from './View.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(
    <View />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

**View.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import Store from './Store.js';

class View extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.Store = new Store();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container" style={{marginTop:'25px'}}>
                <ul className="list-group">
                    <li style={{backgroundColor:'#696969', color:'#f5f5f5', textAlign:'center', padding:'5px', fontSize:'16px', borderRadius:'5px 5px 0px 0px'}}><b>Records</b></li>
                        {Store.getRecords.map((eachRecord,index) =>
                        <li key={index} className="list-group-item" style={{cursor:'pointer'}}>
                            <b>{this.props.eachRecord.name}</b>
                            <button style={{float:'right'}}>Delete</button>
                        </li>
                    )}
                </ul>
                <input type="text"/>
                <button>Add</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default View;
```

**Store.js**

```
import React from 'react';

class Store {

    records: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'First Record',
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Second Record',
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Third Record',
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            name: 'Fourth Record',
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            name: 'Fifth Record',
        }
    ];

    getRecords() {
        return this.records;
    }
};

export default Store;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `this.Store.getRecords().map`

What you have is `Store.getRecords.map`

Two issues there - one, you're calling that method on the class itself, not the instance of the class. Two, getRecords is a method that needs to be invoked - `.method()`, not `.property`

Not really a React issue.

A React issue does exist inside your `<b>` tag - that should just be `eachRecord.name`. `this.props` accesses props passed to the component from its parent. You're not passing any props to `View`.

It's also worth noting that if you're planning to change those records (I see you have delete buttons etc. stubbed out), you would want to store them in the component's state and not as a direct class property. So in your constructor, instead of `this.Store = ...`, you'd have `this.state = { store: new Store() }`, then you can modify it using `this.setState()`
https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly